# Star syntax in PHP

Tags: php, syntax

I have to debug a weird PHP application and today I came across a snippet of code which basically looked like:

```
<?
        if($IdUtil !=0)
        {
           $rowres=mysql_fetch_array($res);
           $TypeUtil=$rowres['Typeuser'];
           //if util is not an admin, does it have rights?
           if ($TypeUtil != ****admin)
           {
                   if($TypeUtil == 4013)
                   {
                        //======================SNIP
```

The line that's stunning me is the `****admin` one. It is used several times in this file, but I never saw it elsewhere. As the application is very buggy I can't run it to use a `var_dump(****admin);` at the moment.

Have you guys, seen somethink like that before? And what does it mean?

Comment: It's a syntax error. Not sure what happened there - maybe the quotes are missing?

Comment: It has no meaning - it's invalid PHP.

Comment: [`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*' in...`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zHk2Hu)

Comment: I finally got the explanation. The client gave me the source code, but replaced every occurence of the hardcoded admin password with stars (****). For security reasons, you see... This projects really scares me more and more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not valid PHP syntax; it will produce a syntax error when run.

Your source file must be mangled somehow.

Answer (score 2):

This code is not valid PHP. There's no way this could have run. Perhaps that string is dynamically replaced by something else before including. (The horror!).

It does seem like some kind of 'magic marker'.